# sumproduct with 3 items (dataframe 1 , dataframe 2 and a row vector)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compute sumproduct in Python using Pandas/NumPy. This is the data I got.

SPG

| Class | Group | AA | BB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AG | SPG | 0.25 | 2.25 |
| AL | SPG | 0.15 | 1.8 |
| LP | SPG | 1.15 | 3.5 |
| TS | SPG | 1.5 | 0.45 |
| HV | SPG | 1.25 | 1.0 |

INIT

| Class | Group | AA | BB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LP | INIT | 0.65 | 3.25 |
| TS | INIT | 4.5 | 1.55 |
| HV | INIT | 2.75 | 0.65 |

DIET

| AA | BB |
| --- | --- |
| 0.004 | 0.15 |

I need to perform sumproduct - sumproduct(SPG,INIT,DIET)/sumproduct(SPG,DIET)

The result must be as below.(TBD-Computation

| Class | Group | F-Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LP | RES | 3.227 |
| TS | RES | 1.791 |
| HV | RES | 0.718 |

I tried with the following, but it is not coming out right and I am not getting the right calculation.

```
import pandas as pd
common_cols = ['AA','BB']
res = (pd.merge(INIT,ISPG,on='Class')[common_cols].dot(DIET)).to_frame()
res['Class'] = (pd.merge(INIT,ISPG,on='Class')['Class']
res['Group'] = (pd.merge(INIT,ISPG,on='Class')['Group']
res
```

Comment: You aren't doing any math at all here, and I can't really guess what you want.  Can you show us what math you need to do?  The term "sumproduct" doesn't do it.  Perhaps you should show us the expected answers.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I have added the excepted answers in the post now. Basically, I need to compute sumproduct of the matched rows with the numeric columns(AA and BB) based on the 'Class' column between ISPG and INIT (that leaves with the LP,TS and HV class) and DIET (AA and BB columns)

Comment: "sumproduct" is just not an adequate description, especially with three sets.  Take the LP rows.  You have four inputs, SPG-AA, SPG-BB, INIT-AA and INIT-BB.  How did you get 3.227 from those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, what we need here is element-wise multiplication and summation along rows. But as far as the last matrix `DIET` is actually a vector, I suggest to use a matrix multiplication on it, i.e. `numpy.dot` or `@` operator.

So here's the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

spg = pd.DataFrame(
    {'AA': {'AG': 0.25, 'AL': 0.15, 'LP': 1.15, 'TS': 1.5, 'HV': 1.25},
     'BB': {'AG': 2.25, 'AL': 1.8, 'LP': 3.5, 'TS': 0.45, 'HV': 1.0}})

init = pd.DataFrame(
    {'AA': {'LP': 0.65, 'TS': 4.5, 'HV': 2.75},
     'BB': {'LP': 3.25, 'TS': 1.55, 'HV': 0.65}})

diet = pd.Series({'AA': 0.004, 'BB': 0.15})

exp = pd.Series({'LP': 3.227, 'TS': 1.791, 'HV': 0.718}).rename('exp')
```

Let's do the math:

```
res = (spg*init@diet) / (spg@diet)
res = res.dropna().round(3).rename('res') 

# NOTE 1: in general SUMPRODUCT may look like this:
#    (spg*init*diet).sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
#                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    need skipna=False to return NA, not zeros on empty records

# NOTE 2: all alignment are provided by pandas automatically
#    because we use common index in spg, init, exp to merge by
```

Check with expected output:

```
assert np.allclose(res-exp, 0), 'Obtained result is far from expected'
print(pd.concat([exp, res], axis=1))
```